# Error CREATE TABLE despues de IIS APPPOOL ASP.NET-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación web que monte en el IIS, la cuestion es que cuando trato de visualizar alguna vista que utiliza datos de la BD me mostraba el error de `IIS APPPOOL\Licorera`.

Revisando en la internet según para reparar ese error era darle los permisos al usuario sobre la aplicación asi:

```
exec sp_grantlogin 'IIS APPPOOL\Licorera' 
use ACME
exec sp_grantdbaccess 'IIS APPPOOL\Licorera'
```

Pero ahora me lanza este error

```
Se ha denegado el permiso CREATE TABLE en la base de datos 'ACME'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Se ha denegado el permiso CREATE TABLE en la base de datos 'ACME'.
```

Como puedo eliminar o corregir este error?

PD: Estoy utilizando Autenticación de Windows, el username es ALPHA-2MYT322/baker_000 y mi cadena de conexión en el archivo `Web.Config`es

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ACME" connectionString="data source=ALPHA-2MYT322;initial catalog=ACME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;User Id=baker_000;Password= ;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ACME1" connectionString="data source=ALPHA-2MYT322;initial catalog=ACME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework;User Id=baker_000;Password= ;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en esta pregunta:

**Lo primero**, es que aunque uses autenticación Windows en el web.config la aplicación por temas de seguridad siempre se va a ejecutar con la cuenta asociada al APPPOOL a menos que le indiques al IIS que deseas suplantar la autenticación con la cuenta del usuario actual, para lo cual necesitas establecer lo siguiente en el web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

En este caso ya tu aplicación se empezaría a ejecutar con el usuario que se haya autenticado dentro de Windows y por esta misma razón seria la cuenta que usaría SQL Server para conectarse a la base de datos.

**Lo segundo,** es que cuando usas autenticación de Windows para conectarte a SQL Server no debes establecerle ningún usuario a la cadena de conexión, por que no se va a tener en cuenta, ya que para realizar la conexión a la base de datos el sistema tomará automáticamente el usuario de Windows con el cual se esté ejecutando la aplicación en ese momento.

- Si no suplantas usaría la cuenta: IIS APPPOOL\Licorera
- Si suplantas usaría la cuenta: ALPHA-2MYT322/[Usuario logueado]

**Lo tercero,** ya definido el usuario o los usuarios que van tener acceso a la aplicación, debes dirigirte al SQL SERVER y asignar los permisos correspondientes. Para tú caso parece que adicionalmente a los permisos de consulta necesitas que los usuario tengan permisos para crear estructuras de datos (lo cual no es muy recomendable por temas de seguridad).